# How to transfer data to input?

Tags: javascript

I want to transfer data to hidden input by JS. I try to do it but it doesn't work

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.formmenu_1 formmenu_a  non_1 div').click(function() {
    $('#1_bil').val($(this).html());
  });
  $('.formmenu_1 formmenu_n formmenu_on  non_1 div').click(function() {
    $('#2_bil').val($(this).html());
  });
  $('.formmenu_1 formmenu_n formmenu_on  non_1 div').click(function() {
    $('#3_bil').val($(this).html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1_bil" name="z_bil" class="formmenu_1 formmenu_a  non_1">11111111111</div>

<input type="hidden" id="1_bil" name="1_bil" />
<div id="2_bil" name="z_bil" class="formmenu_1 formmenu_n formmenu_on  non_1">22222222222222</div>

<input type="hidden" id="2_bil" name="2_bil" />
<div id="3_bil" name="z_bil" class="formmenu_1 formmenu_n formmenu_on  non_1">3333333333333</div>

<input type="hidden" id="3_bil" name="3_bil" />
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is incomplete. what do you want? what did not work? explain ore.

Comment: i use cms modx revo for site building. i want to send email with choosed data.  i use input type for it. i use JS for transfer data into hidden input. when i send the mail from site it back empty without choosed data

Comment: Your ids have to be unique. At the moment you're duplicating the id on the `div` and the hidden `input`.

Comment: The selectors are wrong, and you could improve the code length by using `data-*` attributes.

Comment: can you wright the correct code?

Comment: Just change the selectors to be correct and have different IDs

Answer (score 1):

You selectors were wrong and you had multiple identical IDs

Use one class to have one function and read the id or use a data attribute or `$(this).next()`

Also DIVs do not have name attributes

I changed the input to text for visibility - change them back to hidden when ready

```js
$(function() {
  $('div.formmenu_1').on('click', function() {
    $('#' + this.id + '_input').val($(this).html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1_bil" class="formmenu_1 formmenu_a  non_1">11111111111</div>
<input type="text" id="1_bil_input" name="1_bil" />

<div id="2_bil" class="formmenu_1 formmenu_n formmenu_on  non_1">22222222222222</div>
<input type="text" id="2_bil_input" name="2_bil" />

<div id="3_bil" class="formmenu_1 formmenu_n formmenu_on  non_1">3333333333333</div>
<input type="text" id="3_bil_input" name="3_bil" />
```

Or use the ID as name:

```js
$(function() {
  $('div.formmenu_1').on('click', function() {
    $('[name='+this.id+']').val($(this).html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1_bil" class="formmenu_1 formmenu_a  non_1">11111111111</div>
<input type="text" name="1_bil" />

<div id="2_bil" class="formmenu_1 formmenu_n formmenu_on  non_1">22222222222222</div>
<input type="text" name="2_bil" />

<div id="3_bil" class="formmenu_1 formmenu_n formmenu_on  non_1">3333333333333</div>
<input type="text" name="3_bil" />
```

Comment: ok.thanks. but it chooses several data. i must chose only one among 3

Comment: I do not understand what you mean

Comment: site http://respect-krd.ru/ .if you hold bottom 'Заказать стол' and choose 'Выберете стол:' you will see problem. i  dont know english very well for explaining

Comment: Looks like it copies to the input field.